# Unable to kill VNC stale session with correct display ID

Tags: linux, vnc, vncserver

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I don't remember having issues with killing a VNC session before, and I was able to kill the session I was just on :1  but for not the stale :3

[vnc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aIWT.png)

Comment: Does the file `~/.vnc/host:3.pid` exist? Or are there any other `.pid` files in that folder? And what did you find/tried so far after searching for the error?